# How to send specific database records to other files

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

My question is regarding the ability to update a certain record by choosing a single record from a table and going to that selected record in another page with the full data. I know I would have to create another file with all of the input fields I need, but my question is how do I get there and send over the data info that I selected, then how do I echo out that information and allow the record to be updated?

Let's say I have a table called "Products" that looks like this:

```
ID Name Amount

1 Shoes $10 Edit

2 Hats $5 Edit
```

If I click the "Edit" Button next to "Shoes" I want to go to a different page which allows me to edit all of the information for that record selected.

```
  <form method="POST">
   <input name="first" placeholder="First Name">
   <input name="last" placeholder="Last Name">
   <input name="product" placeholder="Product">
   <button name="add" type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
</div>
<hr>
<table>
<thead>
   <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th></th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   <?php
      $stmt = $dbc->query("SELECT * FROM users");
      $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
      ?>
   <form method="POST">
      <tr>
         <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['amount'];?></td>
         <td><button name="edit" type="submit">Edit</button></td>
      </tr>
   </form>
   <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: You can send data using hidden filed! like `<input name="name" type="hidden">`

Comment: Can't you post the information to the next page?

Comment: I don't know how to do this, that is why I'm asking.

Comment: In PHP you get a map with the post information. It's called $_POST. You can use it to collect the parameters you sent, such as $_POST["first"]. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: @ShayminGratitude Can you show me what you mean? I'm guessing you are saying that is how I will get the information, but I am unsure of how to send it over.

Comment: You specify that in the form attributes, I believe. Looks like Saty has this under control. Use the action attribute to specify the page.

Comment: What is 'Edit' ?? I think you're a bit confused about the term 'table' as it applies to a MySQL database and as it applies to an html table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send your form data to next page using hidden field as

```
<form method="POST" action="edit_page.php">// add action here
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['amount'];?></td>
            <input name="name" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['name'];?>">
            <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
            <input name="amount" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['amount'];?>">
            <td><button name="edit" type="submit">Edit</button></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
```

And in `edit_page.php` use

```
$name=$_POST['name'];
$id=$_POST['id'];
$amount=$_POST['amount'];
```

Comment: @Saty Can I do this? `<td><input name="name" value="<?php echo $row['name'];?>" type="hidden"></td>` ... Then how am I actually able to get and use the information on the other file?

Comment: Look in my answer i an adding action in form tag. You need to create a file names as `edit_page.php` and inside this page use `print_r($_POST)` to check your post data

Comment: Ok. I get the data to show up within the `print_r($_POST)` , but how would I specifically use it. Say I want to have an input for the name? Would I do this? `<input name="name" value="<?php echo $row['name'];?>">`

Comment: Awesome, thanks! If I were to write an `UPDATE` query would there be anything special that I would have to write in to update that selected record?

Comment: Also why on certain pages if someone clicks on a certain records, why does the ? come up in the browser with id numbers and what not?

Comment: No you can just write your update query!! We are using post method so none of parameter comes in browser!!

Comment: Is that the best way to do it? Just wondering, trying to learn.

Comment: I think you may need to sanitize the input before putting it in a query. Otherwise a clever user can execute their own SQL statements.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php

Comment: Like this? `$id = $_POST['id'];  $newId = filter_var($id, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);` Then `<input type="text" value="<?php echo $newId; ?>">` ?

Comment: Ok, so I only need to use `htmlspecialchars`? So, `value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($newId;) ?>` Is that right?

Comment: No, you're putting it in an SQL query, right? So you use mysqli_real_escape_string.

Comment: @ShayminGratitude I am trying to learn PDO. Is there a PDO method?

Comment: Use prepared statements. Look at the other answers in the question I linked.

Comment: Just saw that and was about to write that. So, would it be beneficial to the do htmlspecialchars on my first page before hitting the "Edit" button and then filtering the data like I showed above and then doing the prepared statement for the update?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108530/discussion-between-shaymin-gratitude-and-becky).

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method="POST" action="other_page.php">
        <tr>
           <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" />
           <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $row['name'] ?>" />
           <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $row['amount'] ?>" />

            <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['amount'];?></td>
            <td><button name="edit" type="submit">Edit</button></td>
        </tr>
</form>
```

And then in other_page.php:

```
<?php

    $stmt = $dbc->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE `id`=".$_POST['id'].";");
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    ?>


    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>">
        <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" />
        <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $row['name'] ?>" />
        <input type="text" name="amount" value="<?php echo $row['amount'] ?>" />
        <button name="update" type="submit">Edit</button>
    </form>

    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['update'])){ // if the update button is clicked
        // write your update query here, with $id = $_POST['id'] and so on...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I get this error for the query in the edit page. `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING`